# how can i make both the alert function and decimal function work

Tags: javascript, function

```
function check1()
{
    var min = 01;
    var max = 1200;
    var input = document.getElementById('price');

    var is_valid = (min < inputValue || max > inputValue);


    } 
    else {
        alert(inputValue + ' is not between ' + MIN + ' and ' + MAX);
        return false;
```

The script above works well, but it is ignoring some function

how can I make both work?

Answer (score 2):

You are checking for it being less than the maximum or greater than the minimum. Assuming min < max then this will always be true.

You need either an **and** check (for inside range) or to flip the comparisons (for outside range).

Comment: If you flip the comparison you also have to negate the whole result.

Answer (score 1):

The `is_valid` line should be

```
var is_valid = (min < inputValue && max > inputValue);
```

Also, `MIN` and `MAX` are not the same as `min` and `max`.

EDIT: It also seems like you want to display min and max with their decimal digits. If you need two digits, you could do something like this:

```
alert(inputValue + ' is not between ' + min.toFixed(2) + ' and ' + max.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incorrect.

is_valid will be true if inputValue is larger than min OR of it is smaller than max. Since max is larger than min, one of the two will always happen. Change your condition to:

```
var is_valid = min < inputValue && max > inputValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your `is_valid` condition reversed

```
var is_valid = (inputValue >= min && inputValue <= max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake in Logic, change

```
var is_valid = (min < inputValue || max > inputValue);
```

as

```
var is_valid = (min < inputValue && max > inputValue);
```

For [More](http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/510)